# Google map initialize not working with tab

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to initialize Google Map on tab click event because currently I am getting map like this:

[image]

**My Code:**

```
(function($) {

/*
*  render_map
*
*  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $el (jQuery element)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function render_map( $el ) {

    // var
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

    // vars
    var args = {
        zoom        : 16,
        center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // create map               
    var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);

    // add a markers reference
    map.markers = [];

    // add markers
    $markers.each(function(){

        add_marker( $(this), map );

    });

    // center map
    center_map( map );

}

/*
*  add_marker
*
*  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $marker (jQuery element)
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

    // var
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position    : latlng,
        map         : map
    });

    // add to array
    map.markers.push( marker );

    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() )
    {
        // create info window
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content     : $marker.html()
        });

        // show info window when marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            infowindow.open( map, marker );

        });
    }

}

/*
*  center_map
*
*  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function center_map( map ) {

    // vars
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // loop through all markers and create bounds
    $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

        bounds.extend( latlng );

    });

    // only 1 marker?
    if( map.markers.length == 1 )
    {
        // set center of map
        map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
        map.setZoom( 16 );
    }
    else
    {
        // fit to bounds
        map.fitBounds( bounds );
    }

}

/*
*  document ready
*
*  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   5.0.0
*
*  @param   n/a
*  @return  n/a
*/

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.acf-map').each(function(){

        render_map( $(this) );

    });

});

})(jQuery);
```

**I have tried with this code but not worked:**

```
$( ".map" ).click(function() {

    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(center);

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args); //locally scoped in render_map($el)
```

1) map variable is not globally declared.

So when you try to execute this below code, you will suffer an error.

```
$( ".map" ).click(function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(center);
});
```

## Try #1

Try to change `map` as global variable.

## Try #2

Make it as a `delegate` event handler and add the below code to `render_map( $el )` method.

```
$(document).on('click', '.map', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(center);
});
```