# Google map and jquery custom tab trigger resize fails

Tags: jquery

Am trying to trigger my resize map on the click of a tab. My map just appears small on the top left corner of the box.

Am using gmap.js to load the map

```
 $j(".tabbed-area a.tab").click(function (e) {  
    // switch all tabs off  
    $j(".tabbed-area .active").removeClass("active");  
    // switch this tab on  
    $(this).addClass("active");
    // save parent
    var thisEle = this;
     // Now figure out what the 'title' attribute value is and find the element with that id.  Then slide that down.  
     var content_show = $j(thisEle).attr("title");
    // slide all elements with the class 'content' up  
    var mapi;
    $j(".tabbed-area .tcontent[id!='"+content_show+"']").hide(0, function() {
        $j("#"+content_show).fadeIn(200, function(){
        if(mapi != undefined && mapi != null)
            google.maps.event.trigger(mapi, "resize");
    });

    });
    // prevent from scrolling up the page
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Its not working..

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your entire coding, it is really hard to predict.  But following is my guess,

#### option1

I doubt that the varaible **`mapi`** is *not defined* within this scope.  So try to initialize the `mapi` variable *globally*.

#### Option2

Better to use `delegate` event handler like

```
$(document).on('click', '.tabbed-area a.tab', function() {
      //ToDos
});
```

closely related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20210604/1671639)